# Minimizing $\frac{a^TXb}{\|a\|\|b\|}$ given certain constraints.

Tags: optimization, svd

I'm solving a problem which I have reduced to maximizing $\frac{a^TXb}{\|a\|\|b\|}$  given that $X = (AA^T)^{-1/2}AB^T(BB^T)^{-1/2}$, $a = (AA^T)^{1/2}a'$ and $b = (BB^T)^{1/2}b'$. In this case, I know $a', b'$ are some constant vectors.

How can I choose $a', b'$ (constant) to maximize this value? I believe something like SVD may provide insight, but I am not familiar enough with it to say.

I can also assume $A, B$ are wide and full rank.

Comment: If $a'$ and $b'$ are constants, what is the domain over which you're minimizing? I don't see a minimization problem here -- just one of computing a value.

Comment: I wasn't clear: we can pick $a' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b' \in \mathbb{R}^m$.